# Running XCUITest on device gives "Too many instance of this service are already running"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI test suite that I am trying to run on device. But XCode always reports an error[image]

**Things I have already tried:**

1. Clean and build
2. Clean and clear derived data and build
3. Uninstall the app from device
4. Restart the XCode
5. Restart the mac

Is anyone is also having such issue? Please help.

Comment: Doing a clean build got me into this pain, rebooting the mac got me out, but it's not a correct solution.

Answer (score 9):

Restarting the device helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.Then i followed the below steps.

1.clean xcode

2.delete derived data

3.switch off and on iphone.

4.Build & Test it.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have a little faster solution:

Hold power button till shutdown bar appears, then hold main front button (approx. 10s - till shutdown bar disappears). It should clear iPhone RAM.